# How to set OS disk's networking to AllowPrivate 'Private endpoint (through disk access) using Azure Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have a requirement to use Azure bicep to create a virtual machine, where the OS disk's networking needs to set to private

In Bicep: it is defined under the disk resource with property 'networkAccessPolicy' set to 'AllowPrivate'

In portal: it is defined under disk resource page -> networking -> Private endpoint (through disk access)

Approaches:

1. Create the OS disk within virtual machine resource, however there is no option for me to set the networkAccesPolicy
2. Create the OS disk in disk resource, and then attach to the virtual machine resource, however this way I am not allowed to specific 'osProfile' which I need to specify them
   osProfile: {
   computerName: 'string'
   adminUsername: 'string'
   adminPassword: 'string'
   windowsConfiguration: {
   provisionVMAgent: bool
   }
   }

Comment: This idea of having OS disks on private endpoints sparked my interest. Is it this approach, where you use disk pools? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/virtual-machines/disks-pools

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, but it is not a nice solution with **Bicep**, as OS disk needs to be patched to associate **diskAccess** resource and this is association is currently not available - afaik - as a separate resource in **ARM** or **Bicep**. Hence some "Bicep module hopping" approach is required to achieve this patching in stages.

I extended an existing `vm.bicep` template for a virtual machine and added a subnet for the **disks**:

```
...
      {
        name: subnetDiskName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetDiskPrefix
          privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Disabled'
        }
      }
...
```

At the end of `vm.bicep` I added a reference to this subnet, so that I can pass it as parameter to the next stage. The patching needs to be splitted in 2 stages / modules:

1. GET / fetch the OS disk again as an object
2. PATCH / PUT OS disk with the existing objects data + reference to `diskAccess` resource

```
...
resource subnetDisk 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: subnetDiskName
  parent: vnet
}

module patchDisk 'get-patch-disk.bicep' = {
  name: 'getPatchDisk'
  params: {
    virtualMachineName: virtualMachineName
    diskName: vm.properties.storageProfile.osDisk.name
    location: location
    subnetId: subnetDisk.id
  }
}
```

For stage 1 `get-patch-disk.bicep` just retrieve the current OS disk as an object and pass it on:

```
param virtualMachineName string
param diskName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param subnetId string

resource vmDiskGet 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2020-12-01' existing = {
  name: diskName
}

module vmDiskPatch 'patch-disk.bicep' = {
  name: 'patchDisk'
  params: {
    virtualMachineName: virtualMachineName
    diskName: diskName
    vmDiskGet: vmDiskGet
    location: location
    subnetId: subnetId
  }
}
```

Then in stage 2 `patch-disk.bicep` create the `diskAccess` resource along with the `privateEndpoint` and patch it into the OS disk by transferring all given properties from the object just retrieved and adding the properties required for private disk access.

```
param virtualMachineName string
param diskName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param vmDiskGet object
param subnetId string

var privateEndpointName = 'privateEndpoint${uniqueString(resourceGroup().name)}'
var privateLinkConnectionName = 'privateLink${uniqueString(resourceGroup().name)}'

var diskAccessName = 'diskAccess${uniqueString(resourceGroup().name)}'

resource diskAccess 'Microsoft.Compute/diskAccesses@2020-12-01' = {
  name: diskAccessName
  location: location
  tags: {
    vmName: virtualMachineName
  }
}

resource privateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2020-06-01' = {
  name: privateEndpointName
  location: location
  tags: {
    vmName: virtualMachineName
  }
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: subnetId
    }
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: privateLinkConnectionName
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: diskAccess.id
          groupIds: [
            'disks'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource vmDiskPut 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2020-12-01' = {
  name: diskName
  location: vmDiskGet.location
  properties: {
    diskAccessId: diskAccess.id
    networkAccessPolicy: 'AllowPrivate'
    creationData: vmDiskGet.properties.creationData
    diskSizeGB: vmDiskGet.properties.diskSizeGB
  }
}
```

### DISCLAIMER

I guess the smarter solution is to create the `diskAccess` resource along with the VM in one Bicep template, then return `diskAccess.id` and `vm.properties.storageProfile.osDisk.name` as output parameters. With these output parameters use a simple `az disk update -n "{diskName}" --network-access-policy AllowPrivate --disk-access "{diskAccessId}"` to do the patching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I had followed a solution posted in this tutorial
https://thedummylivings.com/azure-bicep-how-to-set-os-disks-networking-to-allowprivate-private-endpoint-through-disk-access/

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and also investigated the two mentioned approaches in the question. Together with Microsoft support we were not able to implement any of those approaches.

I ended up creating a [deploymentScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep) that run a simple AzureCLI command to set the `network-access-policy` of the osDisk to `DenyAll`:

```bash
resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: identityName
  location: location
}

resource roleAssignmentId 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: roleAssignmentIdName
  scope: resourceGroup()
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: contributorRoleId
    description: 'Assign the user-managed identity the Contributor Role on the Resource Group'
    principalId: identity.properties.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}

resource DenyAllNetworkForOSDiskResource 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'DenyAllNetworkOSDisk'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.45.0'
    cleanupPreference: 'Always'
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H'
    scriptContent: 'az disk update -g my-resource-group -n ${vmOSDiskName} --network-access-policy DenyAll'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    vmResource
  ]
}
```

where

- `vmOSDiskName` is the name of the osDisk given in the resource definition of the VM, and
- `vmResource` is the symbolic name of the VM Resource within the Bicep file